# Random string probability calculation

Tags: c#, random, cryptography

I am using the RNGCryptoServiceProvider to generate a 256-bit length random string (not number), from the characters a-z/A-Z/0-9.

I am required to generate some statistics with regards to the feasibility of collisions (what is the chance, and how many could occur) when generating `<x>` tokens per second but am slightly struggling to show this in a good way?

Is there a formula already used for working out such probabilities?

I had a look around at similar for SHA-256 calculations but I am not sure if it fits this model exactly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

edit: code shown

```
public string Token(int length, string chars)
    {
        using (var generator = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            var bytes = new byte[length];
            generator.GetBytes(bytes);
            var chars = bytes.Select(b =>  availableChars[b%availableChars.Length]);
            var token = new string(chars.ToArray());
            return token;
        }
    }
```

length is 64 in this instance, and available chars is as indicated, taken from a string of 0-9A-Za-z

Thank you

Comment: "I am using the RNGCryptoServiceProvider to generate a 256-bit length random string (not number), from the characters a-z/A-Z/0-9." - you haven't posted any code, but there is a strong likelihood that you will be doing it incorrectly. Pearson's Chi-square test would be the first port of call.

Comment: Added example code in my original question

Comment: Is this a practical problem or for studies?

Comment: Practical problem, random generation of unique short lived session identifier. It is working nicely (modulus comments/changes aside) - but being asked for statistics because it is 'technically' possible that a collision could occur in theory at some point - and just struggling with how to accurately feed back a probability in this instance

Comment: You could also use a [UUID](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122) which "can guarantee uniqueness across space and time." There is little reason for concern with a cryptographically secure random number generator, the errors are generally in the implementation, see goto fail, heartbleed, Ashley Martin, [The Hacker News](http://thehackernews.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate 32 random bytes, the use Convert.ToBase64 to make it into a string. The conversion that you have right now is unnecessary.

Basic probability theory, to be found on the web, tells you that this is secure. No researcher has ever generated a 256 bit collision.

Comment: So don't worry about passing a sequence of allowed characters, you mean, and simply base 64 the bytes returned, and using the RNGCryptoServiceProvider for the random generation is still sound, correct?

Comment: Yes, it the base64 does not throw a single bit away so it's safe. Contrary to the availableChars transform.

Comment: Base64 has extra, disallowed characters.  The question only allows 62 characters: A-Z, a-z, 0-9.  Base64 strings may include +, / and = as well.

Comment: no theoretical reason the identifier cannot include the extra 2 characters, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

There will be a small bias when mod (%) is used.

See if there is a method that resurns a range, in the "C" world there is [arc4random-uniform()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html).

See [How much bias is introduced by the remainder technique?](http://ericlippert.com/2013/12/16/how-much-bias-is-introduced-by-the-remainder-technique/), use the code provided:

Adapt to C#

```
while(true)
{
  int value = rand();
  if (value < RAND_MAX - RAND_MAX % range)
    return value % range;
}
```

As for the randomness, a cryptographically secure random number generator should have essentially no bias. Do check the details WRT the one you choose. There are hardware USB attachable true hardware randon number generators available.

You could also use a [UUID](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122) which "can guarantee uniqueness across space and time."